# Unrecognized selector sent to instance collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

After I rename my header, implementation and xib files, I had the "Unknown class in Interface Builder file" error. I found the solutions online, and now it leads to another problem. "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" error. Search all the solutions online, but none of them works for me. Before I rename, everything goes well.

**Main.m**

```
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
[cell setCollectionData:articleData];
```

**CustomCell.h**

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
- (void)setCollectionData:(NSArray *)collectionData;
@end
```

**CustomCell.m**

```
@interface CustomCell ()
  @property (strong, nonatomic) CustomCellView *collectionView;
@end

@implementation CustomCell
@synthesize collectionView = _collectionView;

- (void)setCollectionData:(NSArray *)collectionData {
    NSLog(@"%s","inside");
    [_collectionView setCollectionData:collectionData];
}
@end
```

Comment: Is a solution to delete a class and create a new one with proper name?

Comment: I can't find a method called `setCollectionData` on `UICollectionView`. Are you sure that exists?

Comment: @Fogmeister, _collectionView is not a UICollectionView. It is of type CustomCellView

Comment: May be it would help if you show all the places you renamed